# Is it possible to present a modal view controller on the iPad without dimming the background?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I would like to present a modal view controller that doesn't dim the content behind it. Just using the standard presentViewController. Just adding the subview of the view controller to the parent view causes problems.

Comment: That seems like a potentially-confusing UX, due to lack of consistency with modal dialogs in general.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The purpose of a modal view controller is to take over the whole screen and make the user deal with whatever you want them to do before returning to the main flow of the app. This is done by covering the whole screen, or dimming the uncovered part of the screen (on iPads).

Comment: It is a special circumstance that I believe merits an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // remove the dimming view if needed, when this view controller will appear as modal
    id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator> transitionCoordinator = self.transitionCoordinator;
    if (transitionCoordinator.presentationStyle != UIModalPresentationNone) {
        for (UIView *transitionContainerSubview in transitionCoordinator.containerView.subviews) {
            if ([NSStringFromClass([transitionContainerSubview class]) isEqualToString:@"UIDimmingView"]) {
                transitionContainerSubview.hidden = YES;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `UIModalPresentationStyle` perhaps?

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIModalPresentationStyle) {
UIModalPresentationFullScreen = 0,
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_3_2
UIModalPresentationPageSheet,
UIModalPresentationFormSheet,
UIModalPresentationCurrentContext,
#endif
};
```

You can specify the type of modal presentation using `setModalPresentationStyle:` on your view controller before calling `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

Comment: How does this answer the question about not dimming the rest of the screen?

Comment: I don't believe any of these styles accomplish what I am after.

Comment: @kyleplattner Technically, using "FullScreen" does because the entire screen is covered so nothing appears dim. :)

Comment: @rmaddy your second comment answers your first comment. Changing the presentation style to `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` doesn't dim the screen which is what I was (poorly) trying to indicate with my answer ;]

Comment: How do I make sure that UIModalPresentationFullScreen doesn't make the modal view take up the whole screen?

Comment: @kyleplattner `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` does exactly what it says on the tin. It presents a modal view that covers the full screen. I suggest you read the documentation on each one for a more detailed description: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical

Comment: Ok, so I am back to my original problem. How can I display a view that doesn't take up the full screen and doesn't dim the background.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to add a view as a subview rather than as a modal viewController. I don't know your particular use, but from the sounds of it the logic should be in the same controller anyway.

```
myControllerThatWasModal.view.layer.opacity = 0.0f;
myControllerThatWasModal.view.hidden = YES;
[self.view addSubview:myControllerThatWasModal.view];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
     myControllerThatWasModal.view.layer.opacity = 1.0f;   
}];
```

This was written from memory so forgive any mistakes, and also not that for this to work you need to have an instance of your "modal" view controller in the view controller that it will cover.

Comment: I think the problem is managing a subview instead of pushing a view controller onto the navigation controller. So there is no way to do this with presentViewController?

Comment: That's correct it is more work managing a subview, but it will give you the desired functionality. There is no way to get modal view controller to do what you want; it is hard wired to have the background. From a UX standpoint the background makes a lot of sense, it visually shows the user where their attention is needed, shows that touches will not be received on the viewcontroller in the background, and generally looks less cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

When using iOS 15 or newer, you can use this to prevent dimming of a modal view controller:

```
modalController.sheetPresentationController?.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .large
```

Set this property before calling the `present` method.

Comment: This only works if a `UISheetPresentationController` has been used.